# Deleting array - heap corruption detected

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have this simple code (for making things shorted, the important bits are probably only the constructor and the add method.) (Code updated).

```
#include "general.h"
template <class T>
class Template
{
private:
    T* oldArr;
    T* newArr;
    int oldArrTop;
    int oldArrLen;
public:
    Template();
    ~Template();
    void add(const T& val);
    void print();
};

template <class T>
Template<T>::Template()
{
    oldArr=new T[2];
    oldArrTop=0;
    oldArrLen=2;
    newArr=new T[4];
    //newArr's length is always 2.
}

template <class T>
Template<T>::~Template()
{
    delete[] oldArr;
    delete[] newArr;
}

template <class T>
void Template<T>::add(const T& val)
{
    //add normally
    oldArr[oldArrTop]=val;
    //need to copy 2 elements
    if( oldArrTop%2==1 )
    {
        newArr[oldArrTop]=oldArr[oldArrTop];
        newArr[oldArrTop-1]=oldArr[oldArrTop-1];
    }
    oldArrTop++;
    //need to double array's size
    if( oldArrTop==oldArrLen )
    {
        delete[] oldArr;
        oldArr=newArr;
        oldArrLen*=2;
        newArr=new T[oldArrLen*2];
    }
}

template <class T>
void Template<T>::print()
{
    for (int i=0; i<oldArrTop; i++)
        cout<<oldArr[i]<<endl;
}
```

Here's the code that uses the template:

```
Template<int> a=Template<int>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        a.add(i);
    a.print();
```

However, when I used the template with integers (for example), the first time I delete an array (the first time I get into the "need to doube array's size" part in add, I get a heap corruption error. Anyone knows what the problem is?
Thank you very much!

---

I'm not sure what fixed it, but the heap corruption error is gone. But, instead of printing the numbers from 0 to 9, it just prints a weird number (-842105421). Any ideas why?

Comment: i believe         delete[] oldArr;     is only deleting the pointer to the first element in the array.  you have to go through and delete each individual element in the array

Comment: @timkd127 unless he is making it an array of pointers, that is unnecessary.

@Idan: have you tried moving the `oldArrTop++` outside of the assignment?  Perhaps there is a weird ordering going on with your compiler

Comment: Can you post the code that uses this?

Comment: You have violated [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: hmjd: this is the code that uses it: 
 Template<int> a=Template<int>();
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  a.add(i);
 a.print();
Ed - that's interesting, but is making a copy constructor absolutely necessary even if there is no chance I would want to copy my class?

Comment: Can you update your add code to reflect the changes youve made to avoid the heap corruption error?

Comment: changes added, should have done it voluntarily.

Comment: Try printing the object after each add, and see what it comes out to, you should be able to figure out whats going on by stepping through the logic yourself at that point

Comment: Problem fixed. I thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can here access memory behind your allocated area:

```
oldArr[oldArrTop]=newArr[oldArrTop];
```

When you are adding the second value oldArrTop will become 2 and you will enter `if( oldArrTop%2==0 )`. And in this if your `oldArr` has only two allocated elements but you try to access the third one (since oldArrTop==2 and it means the third element):

```
oldArr[2]=newArr[2];
```

Comment: It's a mistake. I meant to write

     newArr[oldArrTop-1]=oldArr[oldArrTop-1];
newArr is an array with double oldArr's length, where after every two editions the elements of oldArr are copied to newArr.

Comment: @Idan This is definitely the correct answer.  The way your code is posted now, after the second add `oldArrTop` is equal to 2 at that line, which passes `oldArrtop%2 == 0` and will attempt to write to `oldArr[2]` which is outside the bounds of the array.  Then when the program attempts to `delete oldArr[]` it detects the heap corruption

Comment: @Idan in other words, you must put `oldArr[oldArrTop++]=val` after the check `if(oldArrTop==oldArrLen)` to avoid memory overrun

Comment: Oh, so I needed oldArrTop-1 and oldArrTop-2! (or increasing oldArrTop after the second if...) Got it. Thanks!
But I have another problem: it doesn't crash now, but this is my output: -842150451
-842150451
-842150451
-842150451
4
5
6
7
8
9 (new lines instead of spaces). (instead of numbers from 0 to 9). Any ideas about why it happens?

Comment: @Idan I suspect the issue you're seeing now is a result of the way you are copying your items into the `newArr`.  It seems to be missing the first 4 elements (0 - 3)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::vector<T>`. It will manage memory for you (and will double array size if needed :) )

Comment: He may be working on a system for which the stl is not available

Comment: I'm skeptical he's using compiler in 2012, which has support for templates, but shipped without std lib. @Idan?

Comment: Or perhaps it is simply against company policy to code using the STL.  A couple of the game companies I previously worked at had such a policy, as using anything templatized has a tendency to bloat code very quickly

Comment: No need to guess why am I doing it - it's a homework assignment :)